# iterating through a json elemnt after iterating through a list of jsons

Tags: python, json, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a list of jsons i made after web scraping a store website using this code :

```
responses.append(requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers).json())
```

now my issue is that each json , has a specific number of elements, and each element contains ('title', 'id','price','place','region')

I want to iterate through the list of jsons and then iterate through the 48 elements to parse those pieces of information into a CSV file

I've tried this code :

```
data = []
for j in responses : #iterating through the list of jsons
    for i in range(len(responses[j]['data']['search']['announcements']['data'])) : #iterating through the elements
        data.append([responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['id'],
                     responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['title'],
                     responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['createdAt'],
                     responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['description'],
                     responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['cities'][0]['name'],
                     responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['cities'][0]['region']['name'],
                     responses[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['price']
                     
                 
                ])
        print(j)
Cars_data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id','Car_name','Post_Created','description','city_name','wilaya','price'])
```

i get this error :

> > TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1648\38939902.py in 
> > 1 data = []
> > 2 for j in resp :
> > ----> 3     for i in range(len(resp[j]['data']['search']['announcements']['data'])) :
> > 4         data.append([resp[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['id'],
> > 5                      resp[j]["data"]["search"]["announcements"]['data'][i]['title'],
>
> ```
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
> ```

and before i got out of index error

here is one element of json : (they all have the same format)

```
> {'id': '34456405',   'title': 'Hyundai i10 2012 GLS',   'slug':
> 'city-car-hyundai-i10-2012-gls-alger-centre-algiers-algeria',  
> 'createdAt': '2022-12-07T11:33:06.000Z',   'isFromStore': False,  
> 'isCommentEnabled': False,   'hasDelivery': False,   'deliveryType':
> None,   'description': 'سيارة نقية و مغلفة، فيها شوية صبيغة على برا
> كيما في الصور، محرك ما شاء الله \n 10/10 ما يسخن ما ينقص زيت. 00 مصروف
> ',   'status': 'PUBLISHED',   'cities': [{'id': '556',
>     'name': 'Alger centre',
>     'slug': 'alger-centre-556',
>     'region': {'id': '16',
>      'name': 'Algiers',
>      'slug': 'alger-16',
>      '__typename': 'Region'},
>     '__typename': 'City'}],   'store': None,   'user': {'id': '87200', '__typename': 'User'},   'defaultMedia': {'mediaUrl':
> 'https://cdn9.ouedkniss.com/400/medias/announcements/images/gJJJl/7LIA1J26v5LTHmkp9Bn4zNr4NTrHwF1lJ95P4UZm.jpg',
> '__typename': 'AnnouncementMedia'},   'price': 1450000,  
> 'pricePreview': 145,   'priceUnit': 'MILLION',   'oldPrice': None,  
> 'priceType': 'FIXED',   'exchangeType': None,   '__typename':
> 'Announcement',   'smallDescription': [{'valueText': ['255200km'],
>     '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},    {'valueText': ['Petrol'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},    {'valueText':
> ['1.1'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},    {'valueText':
> ['Manuel'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},    {'valueText':
> ['Silver grey'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},   
> {'valueText': ['Grey card'], '__typename':
> 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'}],   'noAdsense': False},  {'id':
> '34453476',   'title': 'Toyota Auris 2009 Auris',   'slug':
> 'average-sedan-toyota-auris-2009-beni-messous-algiers-algeria',  
> 'createdAt': '2022-12-07T11:32:54.000Z',   'isFromStore': False,  
> 'isCommentEnabled': True,   'hasDelivery': False,   'deliveryType':
> None,   'description': '',   'status': 'PUBLISHED',   'cities':
> [{'id': '567',
>     'name': 'Beni messous',
>     'slug': 'beni-messous-567',
>     'region': {'id': '16',
>      'name': 'Algiers',
>      'slug': 'alger-16',
>      '__typename': 'Region'},
>     '__typename': 'City'}],   'store': None,   'user': {'id': '3203586', '__typename': 'User'},   'defaultMedia': {'mediaUrl':
> 'https://cdn9.ouedkniss.com/400/medias/announcements/images/9kzK4/gGlMMM4jDueAFraAUioidvqJYUkYDU9zDRfX0o5N.jpg',
> '__typename': 'AnnouncementMedia'},   'price': 10000,  
> 'pricePreview': 1,   'priceUnit': 'MILLION',   'oldPrice': None,  
> 'priceType': 'NEGOTIABLE',   'exchangeType': None,   '__typename':
> 'Announcement',   'smallDescription': [{'valueText': ['182000km'],
>     '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},    {'valueText': ['Diesel'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},    {'valueText':
> ['2.0 D4D 126ch'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},   
> {'valueText': ['Automatic'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},
> {'valueText': ['Black'], '__typename': 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'},   
> {'valueText': ['Grey card'], '__typename':
> 'AnnouncementSpecDisplay'}],   'noAdsense': False}
```

Comment: you mentioned response as list of dict, so each element is a dict, while looping over it you'll get dict back not index, this is why `responses[j]['data']['search']['announcements'] ['data']`  this line is giving exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try iterate element by element instead of list[index]:

```
for response in responses:
    for item in response['data']['search']['announcements']['data']:
       data.append(item['id'])
```

I found it easier to manipulate the objects itselves

Answer (score 1):

response is your list of dict

```
# response = [{},{}]
base_data = []
for line in response:
    data = []
    for key, values in line.items():
        if key == "id":
            data.append(values)
        elif key == "createdAt":
            data.append(values)
        elif key == "description":
            data.append(values)
        elif key == "cities":
            data.append(values[0].get("name"))
            data.append(values[0].get("region").get("name"))
        elif key == "price":
            data.append(values)
    base_data.append(data)

print(base_data)
```

`[['34456405', '2022-12-07T11:33:06.000Z', 'ارة نقية و مغلفة، فيها شوية صبيغة على برا\n كيما في الصور، محرك ما شاء الله \n 10/10 ما يسخن ما ينقص زيت. 00 مصروف\n ', 'Alger centre', 'Algiers', 1450000], ['34453476', '2022-12-07T11:32:54.000Z', '', 'Beni messous', 'Algiers', 10000]]`

this will get the values from dict and store it in List of list

Comment: i get a list of empty lists when i do that